# take values from text file , python

Tags: python, python-2.7

i want to take input values from text file and use it in equation in python.

Values in text file

for equation1:

```
A=10
B=5
```

For equation2:

```
C=15
D=20
```

Python program:

```
Value1 = A+ 2B
Value2 = D - B + C
```

Any idea how to go about this or where to look for it.
My idea was read the file in python then assign values to variable in python and then use this in equation.
Thanks and regards.

Comment: Sounds like a good plan.  Come back if you have a specific question while implementing that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **pyparsing** module may be of specific interest to you as well, https://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/

This can be used to parse string literals into an equation (things like * / ^ - +) without the use of eval() **particularily important if you are on linux, insecure.**

This way, you could use ConfigParser to read in a section of variables, and the equations that go with, and evaluate them accordingly.

Comment: Pyparsing is no longer hosted on wikispaces.com. Go to https://github.com/pyparsing/pyparsing

Answer (score 2):

You could do achieve this through `re` module.

```
import re
with open('file') as f:
    fil = f.read()
    A = int(re.search(r'\bA=(\d+)', fil).group(1))
    B = int(re.search(r'\bB=(\d+)', fil).group(1))
    C = int(re.search(r'\bC=(\d+)', fil).group(1))
    D = int(re.search(r'\bD=(\d+)', fil).group(1))
    Value1= A+2*B
    Value2=D-B+C
    print str(Value1), str(Value2)
```

Comment: Plus one for the great solution and the patience to read between the lines. There was no question to work with but you pulled it off.

Comment: A = int(re.search(r'\bA=(\d+)', fil).group(1))---in this syntax what does group(1) , number 1 indcates

Comment: 1 indicates the ist captured group.